# Animation transition between activities using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: java, android, animation, android-intent, android-activity

In my android app, I'm making a method that pop all activities and bring up the first activity.

I use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MMConnection.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

As I noticed that the transition was still a left to right animation, does someone know if there is a way to change system animation when starting an activity?

Actually, I'd ideally like to have a right to left transition (like when the return button is tapped)

thanks for help!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

CoolMcGrr is right, you want to use [`overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int%2C%20int)).

To specifically get the standard "back button" transition, I use these as the `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` transitions:

**push_right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

---

**push_right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: Seems to be a better answer to me, given E-Riz actually answered the question rather than just post a link as CoolMcGrrr did. Then again E-Riz was 8 months later to answer it.

Comment: Where would you call the overridePendingTransition? Before or after startActivity?

Comment: @Tur, just read the Javadoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

Answer (score 9):

You should take a look [Activity.overridePendingTransition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)).

Of course, this requires that you run at least version 2.0 of the SDK.

Answer (score 7):

Problem occurs nowadays because pre-ICS and ICS have different built-in activity transitions.
This is much cleaner than defining your own animation and SDK independant:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MMConnection.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
this.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will start the activity (not visible yet) and play the "activity finish" transition to the new activity.

Answer (score 7):

I used this code:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

You can see these examples in [GmailAnimation](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/GmailAnimation) or [LopeAnimations](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/LopeAnimations). Also you can see more in this [Blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/gmail-overriding-pending-transition/#sthash.CEhJwJLg.dpbs).