# Android - Slide Back to Home Screen

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I've created a "back to home" type button in Android by using the code:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Home.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

However, when android transitions to the Home activity, it slides the activity in from right-to-left, giving the user the impression that a new activity was launched. The user then expects that when pressing "back", the previous activity would come up, which is obviously not the case.

How can I tell android to slide backwards (i.e. from left-to-right) so that the transition indeed gives the appearance of closing the previous activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the animation by calling [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) after `startActivity()`.

Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html) example from google.

Take a look at how to create an [animation resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

Some more detail (copied from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504619/animation-transition-between-activities-using-flag-activity-clear-top)):

To specifically get the standard "back button" transition, I use these as the `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` values to `overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)`:

**push_right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

---

**push_right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```