# New Activity Transition  in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Generally if we use the intent to call the another activity, It'll change our layout with right to left side effect.

But, how can i change this to left to right side effect.

Is that possible using intent or anything?

Anyone Guide me? Best Regards - SPK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API Level 5 you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)

You need to create the xml for the animations, you can see an example on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504619/animation-transition-between-activities-using-flag-activity-clear-top) from SO