# Custom Android Activity Transition

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I was hoping to have the following effect in my android app, a transition from Activity to Activity...

When you click to move onto the next Activity, ... the App waits until that next activity is ready to load (I.e., onResume of the next Activity,...) then it slides the old activity out while sliding the new activity in.  By this I mean, the image of both activities is present at the same time.

Is this possible?  It seems like this would require an INSANE restructuring of my app.

PS, my app has a tab bar which is present at the top of all activities.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504619/animation-transition-between-activities-using-flag-activity-clear-top

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`overridePendingTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) method. It is easy to use, but requires minimum API level 5.

Comment: Thanks and yes I had, however, I don't believe I can use this approach, as I would not be happy to see the top-bar sliding away with the rest of the activity.

Comment: Then try using `ViewPager` or `ViewFlipper`