# Android swipe between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, slider, swipe

Hi I am new to android development.I have two activities in which second one is in library project.Now how can I access it with left swipe in the 1st activity which is in a non library project after integration.Thanks in advance.

Comment: swipe menace?? and explain more with code

Comment: can you explain more or put ur code ??

Comment: I have a library project.After integrate it with an android project,I want get the activity of the library project with a left to right  swipe from the current activity :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html.

Capture Fling events, check if it sufficient swipe, if it is then start the activity.

To achieve swipe animation between activities, you need to use `overridePendingTransition(...)`. Check the first answer here [Animation transition between activities using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504619/animation-transition-between-activities-using-flag-activity-clear-top)